# Google Photo API, retrieving original picture from google pixel Portrait Mode

Tags: google-api, google-photos, google-photos-api, google-pixel

Google Pixel allows to use a "Portrait Mode" that uses some post-processing to create a bokeh effect and blur the background (see for example https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/11/learning-to-predict-depth-on-pixel-3.html). Once uploaded to google photo, it is possible to visualize (and download) both the blurred image, but also the original.

Using the google-photo-api how is it possible to extract the non-blurred image? Using `mediaItems.search` method seems to return only the default-blurred image.